# Windows Programming: WNDCLASS structure: hIcon member Problem

Tags: c++, winapi

I've Created a custom .ico with VS2010 for a game I'm making with DirectX

When I set the .ico file as hIcon member of my wndClass, it will show in the taskbar, but not in the title bar.

I've read the other threads about this, I've searched google, msdn: no luck... I've tried just about anything I could come up with, it still wouldn't show.

The weird thing is: when I switch the hIcon to a default icon (like IDI_ERROR) it will show both in taskbar and in title bar, but not with my custom made .ico

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
HICON Icon = LoadIcon( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_ICON_MYTETRIS) );

WNDCLASS wndClass;
ZeroMemory(&wndClass,sizeof(wndClass));

wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wndClass.hIcon =  Icon;
wndClass.hbrBackground = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndClass.lpszClassName = _T("WindowClass0");

if (RegisterClass(&wndClass) == false) {
    return -1;
}

RECT rc = {0,0,300,225};
AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(_T("WindowClass0")
            ,_T("2D_DirectX_Tetris")
            ,WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
            ,CW_USEDEFAULT
            ,CW_USEDEFAULT
            ,rc.right - rc.left
            ,rc.bottom - rc.top
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,hInstance
            ,NULL );
if( hWnd == false) {
    return -1;
}

ShowWindow( hWnd, iCmdShow );
```

Comment: hmm... setting breakpoints I've discovered that my LoadIcon() returns 0x00000000. That seems even weirder because it still shows in the taskbar =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify an instance handle in your call to LoadIcon so it knows which module's resources to use.
The standard icons *require* a NULL instance, that's why they work for you.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sorry, my first thread. I've accepted it now